# ActiveWeb - rendering parent attribute value

Tags: activejdbc, javalite, activeweb

Suppose `Author` belongs_to `Boook`.
Is it possible to do the same as in Rails templates in a Freemarker template:

```
"author": ${book.author.last_name}
```

I tried without success. May be my syntax is wrong or I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `include()` and pre-load objects for this. 
Please, see: http://javalite.io/lazy_and_eager#eager-simultaneous-loading-of-parents-and-children

You would need to experiment with code a little. In the worst case, you can add a method to a model and call that from a template.

Comment: OK, depending on use or not `include`, I create getter/setter for the needed model attribute. Thank you.